# Redirect to requested URL if already authorized in VueJS Router

Tags: url, vue.js, authorization, router

I'm trying to understand the VueJS router model by [building this tutorial app](https://github.com/academind/yt-devmeetup-vue-firebase). The app redirects you to the home page if you try to open a direct link like *https://example.com/meetups* even if you already logged in and authorized. Why is that and how to open the requested URL instead?

**auth-guard.js**

```
import {store} from '../store'

export default (to, from, next) => {
  if (store.getters.user) {
    next()
  } else {
    next('/signin')
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
    Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      name: 'Signup',
      component: Signup
    },
    {
      path: '/signin',
      name: 'Signin',
      component: Signin
    },
    {
      path: '/meetups',
      name: 'Meetups',
      component: Meetups,
      beforeEnter: AuthGuard
    },
    {
      path: '/meetup/new',
      name: 'CreateMeetup',
      component: CreateMeetup,
      beforeEnter: AuthGuard
    },
    {
      path: '/meetups/:id',
      name: 'Meetup',
      props: true,
      component: Meetup,
      beforeEnter: AuthGuard
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile',
      component: Profile,
      beforeEnter: AuthGuard
    }
  ],
  mode: 'history'
})
```

Comment: can you show the contents of your `store.js` file?

Comment: Yes, do you mean this one? https://github.com/academind/yt-devmeetup-vue-firebase/blob/20-split-modules/src/store/index.js

Comment: how do you know that you are already authorized? `store.getters.user` - does this return a value? given this link https://github.com/academind/yt-devmeetup-vue-firebase/blob/20-split-modules/src/router/auth-guard.js - you should be navigating to the requested url if you are signed in else you should be navigating to the sign in page.

Comment: Yes, it returns the user ID: "id": "1234567890" - Any ideas why the redirect happens?

Comment: You use Vue router with `mode:history` in SPA and you should already set redirect rule at your backend(apache, iis etc), then in the address bar of the browser, you type in one url like `https://example.com/meetups `, it will redirct to `index.html` or whichever you already set up.

Answer (score 1):

The `auth-guard.js` will redirect someone to the sign in page if the store `user` is null.

**When does the store user get updated?**

Inside main.js:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.$store.dispatch('autoSignIn', user)
  }
})
```

the `onAuthStateChanged` method is **async**, meaning that it might finish executing **after** you have asked the browser to go to a page that is guarded by `auth-guard.js`.

This is mostly what happens if you open a new tab or window and type in the url of a guarded page.
This behaviour would work properly if first, the site is fully loaded on an unguarded page (let's say /signin) and then the user would try to click on a guarded page (let's say /meetups). By the time the user clicks on the link, there is a good chance the `onAuthStateChanged` method will have returned and commited to the store ( `this.$store.dispatch('autoSignIn', user)` ), allowing `onAuthStateChanged` to execute properly.

**EDIT**

One way to solve this problem would be to instanciate the Vue app only once the `onAuthStateChanged` has returned a user like so:

main.js

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyCFYWd6FpR53u4hSPXQSjOYeZNPF1FxG2M',
    authDomain: 'yt-devmeetup.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://yt-devmeetup.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'yt-devmeetup',
    storageBucket: 'gs://yt-devmeetup.appspot.com'
})
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
        store.dispatch('autoSignIn', user)
        store.dispatch('fetchUserData')
    }
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router,
        store,
        render: h => h(App),
        created() {
            this.$store.dispatch('loadMeetups')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but what do I need to change in the code to let authorized users enter the direct link without getting redirected to the index.html?

Comment: I have update the answer with a possible solution: instanciating the Vue app only after the Firebase authentication callback.